# Run keydown event handler after the value of a <textarea> has been changed

Tags: jquery

The keydown handler that I want to run when text is added into a `<textarea>` is being executed before the value of the `<textarea>` is even changed. I would like to run my handler after the text is added.

Here's my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NJDTV/).

I do not want to delay the function via `setInterval()` or use the keyup listener.

Comment: What's wrong with keyup?

Comment: I posted a simplified version of the code I'm working on. I can not use keyup in the actual code for reasons that I do not want to go into detail on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's kinda hacky, but if you must: **[Live demo (click).](http://jsfiddle.net/u56w9/)**

```
$("textarea").keydown(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log($('textarea').val()); 
    },0);
});
```

The value of the textarea won't be set until after the keydown event fires, so `keyup` is preferable. If you want to use `keydown`, I think the only solution is to throw off the call stack with a `0` time `setTimeout()` so that the rest of the code will be fired after the value is registered.

Comment: This will suffice, but I will wait to see if a cleaner solution is posted before accepting.

Comment: @cinderblock I don't think it can be done, but I'm open to being wrong :)